# How to deprecate A CustomView and show the deprecation at the XML Layout

Tags: android, deprecation-warning

Is it possible to deprecate a CustomView and also make the xml layout reflect the deprecation?

So for example I deprecated my custom view as such:

```
@Deprecated
class SomeCustomView()
```

then I want the xml layout using this customview to have an indication that it is deprecated, maybe something like:

<<s>com.sample.directory.SomeCustomView</s>
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"/>

is this possible?

Comment: you can make a custom preview of the view in layout editor, and indicate somehow that it is deprecated. To detect the layout editor, you can use `isInEditMode()` method

Comment: Yes, that's definitely possible and you're on right track. That's how `@Deprecated` tag works in **xml files** when you've used particular custom View/ViewGroup.

Comment: Guys, I dont get it, can someone demo it to me? I deprecated my class but my layout xml statys the same without the strikethrough.. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in front of all the constructors and class name of your custom view.

```
/** @deprecated */
    @Deprecated
```

Comment: I tried adding the `@Deprecated(message = "some message")` to all the constructor but it still does not reflect on the xml layout.